# Modify loop variable bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I want to be able to modify the value of the variable used in a for-in loop, from inside the loop.

### Consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100} 
do 
    ((i--))
done;
```

Why is this loop not an infinite-loop? How can it be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for in` loop in shell is not numeric, instead it works on a list of strings that is generated from the next token/construct after `in` and stored in memory. The indicated [control] variable takes the values from the list, one after another in each iteration; there is no way to manipulate that list. You can modify the variable inside the loop, ok, but at the next iteration it will get the next value of the list.

In other words, the control variable *is not* a *control* variable, it's only a placeholder to refer to the *current* items of the list (better: it does not "refer", it contains *a copy* of the referred item).

This means that the number of iterations is predetermined once, when the list of string is created. The number of iterations is equal to the number of strings in the list (of course you can *break* inside the loop).

Other languages have similar constructs, like `for each ...`, or using iterators and so on.

The real thing about `for` can be explained with the following example:

```
for a in *
do echo $a
done
```

is really interpreted as

```
for a in file1 file2 file3 file4 ie all the files in current directory
....
```

as is in fact perfectly legal to write

```
for a in 1 2 3 4 A B C D
...
```

Last note. I said the list of a `for` is kept in memory. I opened two terminals, launched a `for` in one, at checked the memory consumption in the other using free(1).

```
for a in 1 2 3; do sleep 50; done
...gives...
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        246596     224712      21884          0      33948      71584


for a in $(seq 1 1000000); do sleep 50; done
...gives...
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        246596     242864       3732          0       8400      24668
```

(notice the drop of buffers from 33948 to 8400, and the cached from 71584 to 24668). Finally ask for ten times more:

```
for a in $(seq 1 10000000); do sleep 50; done
...gives...
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        246596     243492       3104          0        688       8700
```

(more drop of buffers). The kernel is trying to find more memory and, doing that, slows down the poor little computer!

This shell `for` is very nice and powerful, but beware of the length of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not a C-style loop. The condition to exit the loop is not anyhow related to the value of `i`. It will just loop over the range from 1 to 100 and that's about it.

You can use C-style for-loop in bash if you have to:

```
for ((i=1; x<=100; i++)); do
    ((i--))
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when you say _The condition to exit the loop is not anyhow related to the value of i._, then why if I `echo $i` the incremented value is echoed?

Comment: You can think it this way. `{1..100}` will generate a list with 100 items. The for-in-loop will assign a value from the list to variable `i` until the list is empty. In the loop body the variable `i` gets decrements but on the next loop round we will simply assign the next value from the generated list no matter what the value of `i` is at the moment.